# Unable to establish a secure connection to Stripe using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

I'm following an online tutorial to establish stripe payments. After entering the card details in **test mode**, the instructor's page displayed a message "Payment successful" from **create.html.erb** file.

However, I'm stuck with an error saying **Stripe::APIConnectionError in ChargesController#create** Please check the screenshot below, it says it has something to do with Openssl version although I've the latest version installed.

[image: Error message I got]

After running the command it asked me to, I got this displayed in my cmd: ***Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)***

**charges_controller.rb**

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

    def create
    # Amount in cents
    @amount = 500

    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => params[:stripeEmail],
      :source  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      => @amount,
      :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
      :currency    => 'usd'
    )

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
  end

end
```

I recently started learning Rails, any help on this would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try running the OpenSSL command from the command line as described in the error message?

Comment: @dan-klasson: Yes. It displayed the following: Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)

Comment: `openssl s_client -connect api.stripe.com:443 -tls1 -servername api.stripe.com` connects as expected. Use TLS 1.0 and above (`-tls1`), and use server name indication (SNI) (`-servername`). You can also clear the *Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)* by using `-CAfile` option with [***`GTE CyberTrust Global Root`***](http://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm).